# Buenas prácticas al parsear JSON en Android

Tags: android, json

Mediante Django Rest Framework recojo alrededor de 20 objetos. Cada objeto esta formado por 22 atributos de tipo `String`. `Nombre`, `url_icono`, `dirección`, etc.

En la `Activity` principal, mediante un `GridView`, muestro el ícono con el nombre. Al pulsar un elemento se lanza una segunda `Activity` la cual mostrará mas datos relacionados (los 22 atributos restantes).

La duda es, ¿cuál es el procedimiento adecuado?

1. En el `main` recoger todos los datos de cada elemento.
2. En el `main`, descargar únicamente el ícono y el nombre y en la segunda `Activity` realizar una nueva conexión para recoger el resto de datos de ese elemento.

Comment: 2 casi simpre es la mejor opción, mas alguna opción de cache de datos

Comment: Y recomiendas tener dos tipos de modelo de objetos? Iconos (url_imagen y nombre) y otro modelo Deporte (Por ejemplo) con el resto de datos? O con un modelo es suficiente e ir seteandolo según el camino elegido por el usuario?

Comment: Usa todos los modelos de datos que necesites, no pongas todo en una sola clase (entidad, modelo) ya que haras un antipatron de diseño: **Clase Gorda**: Dotar a una clase con demasiados atributos y/o métodos, haciéndola responsable de la mayoría de la lógica de negocio. [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipatr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)

Comment: Yo diria que depende. Si solo tienes un servicio que siempre va a traer todos los objetos de golpe y esos datos no varían tan a menudo, utiliza 1, y en el primer activity lo guardas en una especie de caché compartido entre el 1er y el 2do activity, esto para que no haya tanta interacción pesada a través de la red. Si tienes tus servicios distribuidos en 1 que te indica los datos principales y otro para ver el detalle de cada uno, entonces te recomiendo la opción 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por lo que he trabajado, recoger 20 objetos de 22 atributos cada uno ... es nada. Es decir, no es una trama crítica.
Lo que sí es crítico y pesado a nivel de procesamiento es realizar un request a un servidor repetidamente.
Personalmente (ya algunos dirán si sí o si no) recomendaría; siempre y cuando sea una información manejable, traer todo de golpe y persistirlo localmente, de esa manera te ahorras las consultas al servidor y tu aplicación se ejecutaría de mejor manera. Y sugiero persistir (en un fichero JSON o una BDD) porque no deberías almacenar estructuras de datos en memoria, mucho cuidado con eso.
Al persistir localmente las consultas, entra el tema de la actualización de tu copia local vs los datos del servidor, entonces debes establecer una cuota (o evento) que dispare una actualización, pero te aseguro que el usuario será feliz con una copia local.
Es lo que te puedo recomendar de acuerdo a mi experiencia, espero te ayude.
Nos comentas, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

A menos que estés lidiando con conexiones **muy** lentas o que los datos sean pesados(a mi parecer mas de 1mb) hazlo en una sola petición.
Esto te evita la [sobrecarga de los headers en las respuestas y peticiones HTTP extra](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http).

También te evita el tiempo extra que implica la petición como tal, es decir el tiempo desde que el usuario hace la petición; la petición llega al servidor, es procesada y finalmente la respuesta llega al usuario de nuevo. Este tiempo es llamado [RoundTrip Time (RTT)](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/round-trip-time), y probablemente en tu caso el RTT es mayor que el tiempo de descarga de los datos.

No hay una respuesta que sea válida para todos los casos, en el tuyo usaría una sólo petición pero es bueno analizar cada caso que se te presente.

Answer (score 1):

Simple y sencillamente si lo más probable es que accedas a una segunda `Activity`, recomiendo un único request, el cual obtendría todos los datos, más aun si únicamente generaria 20 objetos con 22 atributos cada uno, esta cantidad de objetos no creo considerarla como una alerta que pueda generar un problema de memoria, la opción sería "recoger 20 objetos de 22 atributos cada uno" en el `MainActivity`

**En el main recoger todos los datos de cada elemento.**